# Функция .replace заменяет не все теги

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Друзья, проблема такая. Есть строка:

```
г. тест,<br/>ул. тест д.15<br/>(бывший кирпичный завод)
```

В результате на экране я получаю строку в таком виде:

```
г. тест,
ул. тест д.15<br/>(бывший кирпичный завод)
```

Вот мой код:

```
  $("#partner_address").val(obj.address.replace("<br/>", "\n"));
```

Вопрос, почему функция .replace заменяет только первый найденый тэг, и не заменяет всех тегов которые есть в строке? как это можно исправить?

Comment: Напишите вместо `"<br/>"` это `/<br\/>/g`.

Comment: Сработало! спасибо!